# Changing media screen makes div overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I am using Bootstrap and the divs are 4-columns each *(col-md-4)*. Based on Bootstrap with 12-columns it means that in the PC media screen it would be three divs at each row. Below 991px it's standard that each 4-columns covers the whole screen. Please see screenshot:

[image]

[image]

However, I want the 4-columns to only cover 50% of the screen when screen size is between 600px and 990px. Meaning there are two divs at each row. This is something I have succeeded in, but there are some issues.

When loading the page at mobile portrait (approx < 530px) everything loads correctly. The div does not overlay each other.

[image]

When loading the page at mobile landscape, or ipad portrait (approx > 740px) everything loads correctly. The div does not overlay each other.

[image]

When flipping the screen from either mobile portrait to mobile landscape or opposite it's starting to act strange. The divs are clearly overlaying each other.

[image]

The effect I want has been adding by using the following **CSS**:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1200px) { #isotope-list img { height: 100%; } }

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 990px) { #isotope-list .col-md-4 { width: 50%; } #isotope-list img { height: 100%; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) { #isotope-list img {  height: auto; }}
```

When removing this CSS it goes back to standard Bootstrap and there are no divs overlaying each other. This means there must be something wrong with the connection between my CSS and Bootstrap. Meaning there should be something I could add to prevent this from happening.

The site can be found here: http://goo.gl/9IsTIl

**Here is the HTML/PHP if needed:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="isotope-list">    
            <div class="item col-md-4"> 
                <div class="content grid lefttext">
                    <figure class="effect-lily">
                        <!-- image -->
                        <figcaption>
                        <!-- caption -->
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>     
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
The script that may interfare with the CSS: http://goo.gl/NnLwgo

**Edit 2:**
This is the following I get when going from portrait to landscape in android browser on mobile:

[image]

Comment: Are you using something to do the effect of re-arrange  items? your items are overlapping because , something set styles like this    /* position: absolute; */
  /* left: 0px; */
  /* top: 222px; */

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with Bootstrap. @JesusAngulo is correct. I looked at your page, and whatever script you are using for your animation (which is very cool I might add) is miscalculating what your elements `top` style should be. You should take a look at this algorithm.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Then I would believe it will be the isotope script. I will add the shortcut in the post right now. However, the script is compressed, so it could be hard to read.

Comment: It looks like your element's `top` attribute is being calculated by a script packaged with your `theme`. That script being "isotope.pkgd.min.js'. It is hard to tell what the issue is because the script is minified, yet it is possible that the function may be calculating the elements dimensions incorrectly due to the elements `float` property. I would test adding this CSS to your page and see what it does:  `#isotope-list>.item{float:none !important;}`

Comment: Thank you. I testet the code you provided, but nothing happened...

Comment: It's a error of the script that calculate the heigth of the elements and assign a absolute position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is that you have set `height: auto` on the `img` when the screen goes lower `600px`.

Your code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  #isotope-list img {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

So when isotope rearrange your elements, it won't know your image sizes which will cause miscalculation of the positions.

To fix that is to remove that `height: auto` then remove the `max-width` being set on `.grid figure img` which will remove the ugliness during the transition.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  .grid figure img {
    max-width: none;
  }
}
```

The problem left is that the image will exceed the width of it's container, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

What I can think to fix this is to have a good use of the `isotope` [events](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html) so when it finishes arranging the elements, you add class to the images and set it with `max-width: 100%`.

e.g.

```
var $grid = $('#isotope-list').isotope({...});

$grid.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
   $(".grid figure img").addClass("imgArranged");
});
```

Then on your final media query will have to look like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  .grid figure img {
    max-width: none;
  }

  .grid figure img.imgArranged {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Update - Adding the JS stuff**

The settings for your `isotope` can be found [here](http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/isotope.js?ver=1), so when using the `isotope` events, it would be appropriate to write it there.

In your case add this:

```
  // Add class when transition is finished
  $container.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
    $(".grid figure img").addClass("imgArranged");
  });
```

**That file should look like this now:**

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
  $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry'
  });

  // Add class when transition is finished
  $container.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
    $(".grid figure img").addClass("imgArranged");
  });

  //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
  var $optionSets = $('#filters,#filters-undercat'),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
    $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
      filter: selector
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Where should I add the script? In isotope.pkgd.min.js or should I have it in another js-file? You can check out the website now if you'd like. There are some bugs, but I am not sure what. Atleast there are some overlays, etc.

Comment: @Olen I have updated my answer. You can see there the file where you should be adding that.

Comment: Thank you. I can see there are some troubles with the width as you mentioned. I added `width: 100%` to the img, and I believe that solved the problem. If I didn't do anything wrong right now? But there is still an issue. I will post a picture in a sec. The problem appears on android browser on mobile.

Comment: I believe I have done something wrong. I can see now that the jquery with adding new class does not work. The img does not get a new class. I have checked that the JS is being uploaded to the site.

Comment: I see that the isotope is being loaded in the functions.php. Could that be wrong? `function add_isotope() {
    wp_register_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'),  true );
    wp_register_script( 'isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init');
}`

Comment: @olen sorry for getting back to you late. What I can see the problem is that the event `arrangeComplete` doesn't trigger on the initial load of the page. I'll take a look again and see what I can do.

Comment: No problem. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: I have made a followup since the question has partly changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624836/event-does-not-trigger-on-the-initial-load

Comment: @Olen I saw an answer on your latest post, give it a try and let's see if it works.