# Event does not trigger on the initial load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

This is a continuation from my other question regarding [Changing media screen makes div overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570342/changing-media-screen-makes-div-overlay)

This problem is associated with [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). With help from @Robin Carlo Catacutan I have the following [isotope.js](http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/isotope.js?ver=1):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
  $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry'
  });

  // Add class when transition is finished
  $container.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
    $(".grid figure img").addClass("imgArranged");
  });

  $container.on( 'arrangeComplete',
  function( event, filteredItems ) {
    console.log( 'Isotope arrange completed on ' +
      filteredItems.length + ' items' );
  }
);

  //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
  var $optionSets = $('#filters,#filters-undercat'),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
    $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
      filter: selector
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

**I want you to focus on the section where it's supposed to add class when transition is finished:**

```
  $container.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
    $(".grid figure img").addClass("imgArranged");
  });
```

According to @Robin Carlo Catacutan there is a problem with arrangeComplete. The event arrangeComplete doesn't trigger on the initial load of the page.

**The isotope is being loaded in the beginning of functions.php:**

```
//Isotope
function add_isotope() {
    wp_register_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'),  true );
    wp_register_script( 'isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' );
```

**I post all my php within the latest posts in case you find anything suspicious:**

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => (array( 'foto', 'video', 'web' )),
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_taxonomy' => 'any',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category");
            $termsString = "";
                foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { 
                    $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
                }
        ?>               
        <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item col-md-4"> 
            <div class="content grid lefttext">
                <figure class="effect-lily">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('frontpage_thumb'); } ?>
                    <figcaption>
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="uppercase regular whitetext textshadow nomarginbottom"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <p><span class="whitetext thin textshadow"><?php echo(types_render_field( "produkt", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?> / <?php echo(types_render_field( "produsert", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="smoothtrans">Se prosjekt</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>     
            </div> 
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, this is the most important part which is directly related to the question:

```
<div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item col-md-4"> 
     <div class="content grid lefttext">
          <figure class="effect-lily">
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('frontpage_thumb'); } ?>
              <figcaption>
                  <div>
                       <h2 class="uppercase regular whitetext textshadow nomarginbottom"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                       <p><span class="whitetext thin textshadow"><?php echo(types_render_field( "produkt", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?> / <?php echo(types_render_field( "produsert", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?></span></p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="smoothtrans">Se prosjekt</a>
               </figcaption>            
          </figure>     
     </div> 
</div>
```

**Not sure if relevant, but as summary of what I am using related to this problem:**

- Wordpress
- Isotope
- Bootstrap

**What I have tried:**

- Changing the order of where the isotope.js is being loaded. Tried
  including it in the header, right before the closing of body tag and
  so on.
- Searching online for a similiar problem (not found)
- Renaming `$container` to `$grid`
- Changing what element the addClass is going to affect

The page can be found [here](http://goo.gl/3NXLAh).

Do you have a working solution or any ideas?

Streched images on Android Landscape:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should try (and this is related to your first question as well), since your loading images, is to use [imagesloaded.js](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js). This will allow all images to load before isotope is initiated which will eliminate overlaps [See here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html#how-do-i-fix-overlapping-item-elements). I'm not understanding why do you need to add the class "imgArranged" using javascript if it is in a @media query?

```
var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts

 $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
 $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
 itemSelector: '.item',
 layoutMode: 'masonry'
 });
 });
```

**ADENDUM**

The problem is you are loading jQuery twice, 2 different versions. You need to pick one. If you pick 2.1.4, you don't use query-migrate

This loads first:

```
 <script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
  <script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/collection.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/less.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
  <script src="//use.typekit.net/xti5sne.js"></script>
```

This loads after:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/js/isotope.js?ver=1'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was searching on metafizzy to find the problem, but I guess I was a little bit dull. However, I am getting: `$container.imagesLoaded is not a function`. The imagesloaded.js is currently being loaded in the header. Should I load it a different place, e.g functions.php? Or is there another mistake I have done?

Comment: Thank you. I actually removed jquery from wp-includes earlier, and it crashes the site. So learned that it shouldn't be removed. Also found this online: "The jQuery migrate script will ensure backwards compatibility for any theme/plugin you have that uses deprecated features while the new versions of jQuery is required for most of the WordPress core features, not to mention any plugins relying on it and using the WordPress bundled version to work."

Comment: You need one version of jQuery. If you remove both, no plugins will function and having both causes major problems. So Remove 2.1.4 and move  collection.js, less.js, imagesloaded.js and xti5sne.js after jquery-migrate.

Comment: Thank you. Could be a problem to move all scripts to functions.php because there is where migrate is being included. So I have removed migrate. However, still getting the error with `$container.imagesLoaded` not being a function

Comment: You have to load your isotope.js as the last script loaded, after imagesloade.js. You are calling the imagesloaded function in your isotope.js file before the imagesloaded.js script has been loaded in the page.

Comment: Thanks. Just did some changes. And when isotope.js is being loaded after imagesloaded.js I get the error, but when imagesloaded.js is loaded before isotope.js I don't get any error. I also don't get any overlaying images, but on android browser landscape the images are being streched in the height (like in the other post). I will post a screenshot in a second.

Comment: Problem has been solved. Thank you very much for helping me out! :)